# Compile error trying to use CAGradientLayer

Tags: iphone, ios, gradient, quartz-graphics

I'm trying to use CAGradientLayer and getting an unhelpful compile error. Can't figure out whats wrong. All I'm doing so far is:

```
CAGradientLayer *gradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
```

I've imported `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and I'm getting the warning >

> _OBJC_CLASS_$CAGradientLayer referenced from: objc-class-ref-to-CAGradientLayer symbol(s) not found.

I've tried clean and build but no luck and I can't seem to target anything other than 4.1 in Xcode

Cheers for any help.

Comment: You imported the header files, but did you add the quartzcore framework?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You didn't correctly add the `QuartzCore` framework into your project:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thats lame, I have actually imported it and I have been using it in other parts in my project so didn't think about it. Reimported it and it worked.

Comment: You were exactly right! Thank you for providing the solution to my problem.

Answer (score 6):

You have to add the QuartzCore-Framework to your project.