# removeAllAnimations

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios4

I use `[self.view.layer removeAllAnimations];` for pause animation.but xcode says

> warning: no '-removeAllAnimations'
>   method found

why ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably forgot to link the `QuartzCore` framework into your project.

See my answer here: [Compile error trying to use CAGradientLayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902594/compile-error-trying-to-use-cagradientlayer/3902613#3902613)