# Undefined symbols for architecture i386 - While making UIButton subclass

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uibutton, subclass

I am getting this error:

> Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
>         "_OBJC_CLASS_$_CAGradientLayer", referenced from:
>             objc-class-ref in GradientButton.o
>       ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
>       clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

while trying to make a subclass of UIButton:

this is the h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

@interface GradientButton : UIButton

@property (assign, nonatomic) int borderWidth;
@property (assign, nonatomic) UIColor *buttonColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIColor *borderColor;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *title;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame botderWidth:(int)width borderColor:(UIColor *)bColor buttonColor:(UIColor *)btnColor title:(NSString *)btnTitle;


@end
```

this is the m file:

```
#import "GradientButton.h"

@interface GradientButton (Private)

- (void)initBorder;
- (void)initCorners;
- (void)initColorsAndFont;
- (void)initStyle;
- (void)initGradient;

@end

@implementation GradientButton
@synthesize borderColor, borderWidth, title, buttonColor;

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame botderWidth:(int)width borderColor:(UIColor *)bColor buttonColor:(UIColor *)btnColor title:(NSString *)btnTitle
{
    borderWidth = width;
    borderColor = bColor;
    title = btnTitle;
    buttonColor = btnColor;    

    [self initBorder];
    [self initCorners];
    [self initColorsAndFont];
    [self initStyle];
    [self initGradient];

    return self;
}

- (void)initBorder {
    self.layer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    self.layer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;
}

- (void)initCorners {
    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.height / 2.0f;
}

- (void)initColorsAndFont {
    self.backgroundColor = buttonColor;
    [self setTitle:title forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    self.titleLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    [self setTitleColor:[UIColor blackColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}

- (void)initStyle {
    self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor darkGrayColor].CGColor;
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 1.0;
    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2.0, 2.0);
}

- (void)initGradient {
    CAGradientLayer *layer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    NSArray *colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                       (id)[UIColor whiteColor].CGColor,
                       (id)buttonColor,
                       nil];
    [layer setColors:colors];
    [layer setFrame:self.bounds];
    [self.layer insertSublayer:layer atIndex:0];
    [self setClipsToBounds:YES]; 
}


@end
```

Why???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compile error trying to use CAGradientLayer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902594/compile-error-trying-to-use-cagradientlayer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you add QuartzCore framework in your project?

See this: [add framework to project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3902594/compile-error-trying-to-use-cagradientlayer)

Comment: You are right, you solved my problem. Now why can't I add this button as a subview to another UIView? 


    - (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        
        GradientButton *button = [[GradientButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, 60, 30) botderWidth:0 borderColor:nil buttonColor:[UIColor redColor] title:@"try"];
        [self.view addSubview:button];       
    }


I get Thread1 SIGBRT error